# bootstrap 4 form return value issue

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Im building a site with bootstrap 4 and I added a form. I put it on my server and ran it and it works! Kinda. there are 4 fields, first_name, last_name, email, phone. Validation works and I have it being sent to an email and that works but no matter what is entered in the input fields on the site the email returns this:

```
Name: S S.
Email: S.
Phone: S.
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php
$first_name= S_POST['first_name'];
$last_name= S_POST['last_name'];
$email= S_POST['email'];
$phone= S_POST['phone'];

$email_from =' Company, llc';
$email_subject = 'New Message From A Guest';
$email_body = "Name: $first_name $last_name.\n".
              "Email: $email.\n".
              "Phone: $phone.\n";
$to ="me@business.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("location: index.html");
?>
```

Form HTML:

```
 <form class="form inline d-flex justify-content-center" action="contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
             <br style="clear:both">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
          </form>
```

What could be causing it to only return S as the value for these inputs? ANy help would be appreciated

Comment: you are using "S_" but  should be dollar $_

Answer (score 2):

```
$first_name= S_POST['first_name'];
$last_name= S_POST['last_name'];
$email= S_POST['email'];
$phone= S_POST['phone'];
```

should not be "S_" but instead should be dollar $_

such as:

```
$first_name= $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name= $_POST['last_name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
```

Comment: lol, I saw my error and was going to answer my own question. Thanks though Monday mornig eyes I guess